# Unable to install Google-Earth-Engine-Api in Linux subsystem for Windows

Tags: python, linux, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, google-earth-engine

Ok, I've installed Linux subsystem in my Windows 10 and now following this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/python_install_manual) to install google earth engine inside my Linux subsystem.

When I try to run following command to install GEE API, I get following error (I am getting the same error for "sudo pip install 'pyOpenSSL>=0.11'" command as well.):

```
sudo pip install earthengine-api
```

[image]

```
> Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools,
> tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-PrUuzi/cryptography/setup.py';f=get
> attr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
> '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec' ))" install
> --record /tmp/pip-3eTIvM-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed wit h error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-PrUuzi/cryptography/
```

Then after failing this, I tried to manually download and install the GEE setup.
I copied the downloaded compressed package to folder: "C:\Users\Saurabh\AppData\Local\lxss\home\saurabh"

and then tried to do the **ls -a** to see if I can see the file or not. But it is not visible:
[image]
[image]

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: If you paste your code into your post and surround it with tildes ` like this ` (but without spaces), it will format as code, and your post is more likely to turn up in Google results for the same question (which is how I ended up here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [this thread](https://github.com/SpotlightKid/python-rtmidi/issues/2/#issuecomment-212638972), I updated setuptools and pip to the latest versions and I am finally able to run the earthengine-api without any issue.

Comment: You linked to a thread about the rtmidi package, not the Google Earth Engine. Was that your intent...?